# I want to add value to multiple variable If condition shorthand

Tags: php, if-statement, ternary-operator

I want to add value to multiple variable If condition shorthand but I don't know how to use symbol split between 2 variable

eg. manuscript

```
if(condition) {
    $var1 = "a";
    $var2 = "b";
} else {
    $var1 = "";
    $var2 = "";
}
```

Shorthand [error]

```
(condition) ? $var1 = "a", $var2 = "b"
: $var1 = "", $var2 = "";
```

Comment: `[$var1, $var2] = [$condition ? 'a' : '', $condition ? 'b' : ''];`

Comment: Even sweeter: `[$var1, $var2] = $condition ? ['a','b'] : ['',''];` https://3v4l.org/FrI2e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do it. The `if` statement is fine. It's simple and clear. Try to cram multiple assignments into the `?:` ternary operator, next thing you know you're hacking Perl scripts for spare change in some back alley.

I would write exactly what you have:

```
if (condition) {
    $var1 = "a";
    $var2 = "b";
} else {
    $var1 = "";
    $var2 = "";
}
```

You could potentially write it like this, if you prefer. This is a good choice if you first assign *default* values and the `if` condition assigns less common values.

```
$var1 = "";
$var2 = "";

if (condition) {
    $var1 = "a";
    $var2 = "b";
}
```

If you *really* want to use the ternary operator you could write this, if you're okay writing `condition` twice:

```
$var1 = condition ? "a" : "";
$var2 = condition ? "b" : "";
```